# Using BeautifulSoup to scrape urls from a Google Search

Tags: python-3.x, beautifulsoup

My code is

```
import urllib
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests
import webbrowser

text = 'LastName, FirstName'
text = urllib.parse.quote_plus(text)

url = 'https://google.com/search?q=' + text

response = requests.get(url)
```

I want to get the url of the first search result, how would I go about doing this?

Comment: Your first search result may not be the same as someone else's; please post the search result that is your target output.

Answer (score 0):

You might want to consider for this task:

```
import urllib
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from selenium import webdriver


text = 'LastName, FirstName'
text = urllib.parse.quote_plus(text)

url = 'https://google.com/search?q=' + text

driver = webdriver.Firefox()
driver.get(url)

soup = BeautifulSoup(driver.page_source)
results_links = soup.find('div',{'class':'srg'}).find_all("a")
print(results_links[0].get('href'))
```

output:

> https://www.quora.com/What-is-meant-by-first-name-and-last-name

Answer (score 0):

One of the reasons is because there's no [`user-agent`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/User-Agent) specified, thus Google blocks your request and you receiving a different HTML with different selectors. Learn more about [HTTP request header](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Request_header).

Pass `user-agent` into request `headers`:

```py
headers = {
    "User-agent":
    "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/70.0.3538.102 Safari/537.36 Edge/18.19582"
}
requests.get("YOUR_URL", headers=headers)
```

To get only first link, [use `select_one()`](https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#css-selectors) `bs4` method (*`css` selectors [reference](https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css_selectors.asp)*):

```py
first_link = soup.select_one(".yuRUbf a")['href']
```

---

Code and [full example in the online IDE](https://replit.com/@DimitryZub1/Google-Scrape-Title-Description-Linkpythonbs4#bs4_results.py):

```py
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests, lxml

headers = {
    'User-agent':
    "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/70.0.3538.102 Safari/537.36 Edge/18.19582"
}

params = {
  "q": "what is the best minecraft skin in 2021",  # query
  "gl": "uk"                                       # country to search from
}

html = requests.get("https://www.google.com/search", headers=headers, params=params)
soup = BeautifulSoup(html.text, 'lxml')

# gets the very first link from the search results
first_link = soup.select_one(".yuRUbf a")['href']
print(first_link)

# https://codakid.com/minecraft-skins/
```

---

Alternatively, you can achieve the same thing by using [Google Organic Results API](https://serpapi.com/organic-results) from SerpApi. It's a paid API with a free plan.

The difference in your case is that you don't need to figure out why you didn't get a proper HTML with the data you want since extracting part is already done for the end-user. The only thing that really needs to be done is to iterate over structured JSON and get the data you want.

Code to integrate:

```py
import os
from serpapi import GoogleSearch

params = {
    "engine": "google",
    "q": "best minecraft skin in 2021",
    "hl": "en",
    "api_key": os.getenv("API_KEY"),
}

search = GoogleSearch(params)
results = search.get_dict()

# [0] - first search result
first_link = results['organic_results'][0]['link']
print(first_link)

# https://www.minecraftskins.com/search/skin/2021/1/
```

> Disclaimer, I work for SerpApi.